# How to change the Color of paint inside a timer

Tags: java, swing, timer, paintcomponent

Here is the portion of my code I'm concerned with, When I try to change the color of squaresToDisplay object again using the Timer, it makes the frame white (blank) but it works only 1 time. So when I run this piece of code, it will do what I want 1 time then make the screen blank. I am wondering what causes this specifically. My own assumption is that I might be blocking the EDT when I start the SQTimer, in which case I'm at a loss because I don't know enough java to fix this :/

```
private Timer SQTimer;
startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //Code that removes unrelated things from the frame

        final SquareObjects squaresToDisplay = new SquareObjects(x,y);//Creates the Object based on GUI width and height
        squaresToDisplay.setFocusable(true);
        squaresToDisplay.setVisible(true);//Allows it to be visible
        frame.add(squaresToDisplay);//Adds it to the frame
        SQTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                squaresToDisplay.repaint();
                System.out.println("Repainted");
                }
        });
        System.out.println("Completed adding pixels");
        SQTimer.setRepeats(true);
        SQTimer.start();
    } 
});
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("Beginning of paintComponent");
        System.out.println("Completed making the Graphics objects");
        for(int i = 0;i<(x*y)/64;i++){
        if(xInterceptLocation == 0){
            g.fillRect(xInterceptLocation, yInterceptLocation, 8, 8);
            xInterceptLocation += 8;
        }else{
            Color newColor = changingColors();
            g.setColor(newColor);
            g.fillRect(xInterceptLocation, yInterceptLocation, 8, 8);
            xInterceptLocation += 8;
            if(xInterceptLocation == 1920){
                xInterceptLocation = 0;
                yInterceptLocation += 8;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just for clarification, these to methods are in seperate classes, the first one is in a class called GUI while the second one is in a class called SquareObjects

Comment: There is no need or benefit in creating an array of Graphics object since each item in the array is holding the one and same Graphics object. At best all this does is confuse. Get rid of the array.

Comment: I removed the array, it does the same thing, but it doesnt create the array anymore thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Since all your Timer's ActionListener does is to call `repaint()` on the component, this suggests (and your code confirms) that you've got program logic in your `paintComponent(...)` method. I also recommend that you not do that, that the ActionListener change the state of the class, and that the `paintComponent(...)` use that state to alter its drawing. You'll also want to sprinkle your code with debug statements to see what it may be doing wrong.

Comment: When you say sprinkle with debug statements, do you mean put System output for certain areas of the code that just says whats going on in that area? Since the ActionListener changes the state of the class, then the reason it works the first time is because the squareObject is instantiated while the class still has focus, but when the ActionListener is created, it switches focus to another class and trys to repaint the squareObject but since its part of another class it cant? Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There are two ActionListeners at play here, the JButton's ActionListener, which I assume is only pressed once, and the Timer's ActionListener, which should be called every second. I assume that it's the second ActionListener that's not working, that only works once, correct? If I'm wrong, please clarify. Also, I don't see any EDT blocking code.

Comment: Edit: one problem: you don't appear to be re-initializing your intercepts at the start of the `paintComponent(...)` method

Comment: Sweet! the problem was that the yInterceptLocation was never set back to 0, so when the program repainted, it continued adding 8, thus leaving the screen blank because it was out of the frames bounds. Thank you for helping me, and pointing things out I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad you've got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that the yInterceptLocation was never set back to 0, so when the program repainted, it continued adding 8, thus leaving the screen blank because it was out of the frames bounds.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println("Beginning of paintComponent");

    System.out.println("Completed making the Graphics objects");
    //yIntercept needs to be reinitialized when the repaint(); is called again
    if(yInterceptLocation == 1080){
        yInterceptLocation = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<(x*y)/64;i++){
            if(xInterceptLocation == 0){//If i == 0 then it wont add 8 first (thus preventing a gap)
            g.fillRect(xInterceptLocation, yInterceptLocation, 8, 8);
            xInterceptLocation += 8;
        }else{//Any other time we want to add 8 to space out the squares
            Color newColor = changingColors();
            g.setColor(newColor);
            g.fillRect(xInterceptLocation, yInterceptLocation, 8, 8);
            xInterceptLocation += 8;
            if(xInterceptLocation == 1920){//if xInterceptLocation = 1920 then it adds 8 to yIntercept and sets x to 0 (creating a new line)
                xInterceptLocation = 0;
                yInterceptLocation += 8;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Credits to HoverCraft Full Of Eels, for noticing it wasn't reinitialized